# select all referenced tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example: Say, I have 2 schemas and 4 tables created as

```
    create table a.foo(
      id integer primary key,
      val integer);

    create table b.main(
      id serial primary key,
      val integer references a.foo(id));

    create table b.foo(
      k integer primary key references b.main(id),
      v timestamp with time zone);

    create table b.bar(
      k integer primary key references b.main(id),
      v timestamp with time zone);
```

Psuedo code for what I'm looking for: select all tables where b.main.id is referenced;

The results would look like:

```
    b.main.id | b.main.val | b.foo.k | b.foo.v | b.bar.k | b.bar.v
       1           1           1      TimeStamp    1      TimeStamp
       2           1           2        ....       2        ....
```

Right now I have implemented this query as:

```
   select * from b.main,
            (select *
               from b.foo,
                   (select * from b.bar where b.bar.v > somedate) as morebar
              where b.bar.k = b.foo.k) as morefoo
    where b.main.id = b.foo.k;
```

Back to the question. Is there a feature in Postgres that allows us to perform a select on all tables that reference a primary key? In my case, all tables that reference b.main.id.

I've searched through the Postgresql documentation, but have yet to find what I'm looking for. Suggestions?

Comment: Hi @fbynite, didn't work my answer? This query is "like" `select all tables where b.main.id is referenced;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to find myself a way to automatically select other tables that referenced to a table's primary key. It seems you still have to mention/type the other table manually in your query, but here's a short version of your query using join:

```
select *
from b.main a, b.foo b, b.bar c
where a.id = b.k
and a.id = c.k
```

or

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from b.main as a
inner join b.foo as b on a.id = b.k
inner join b.bar as c on a.id = c.k
```

Comment: Like you, I have yet to find a way to select all rows/columns where a primary key is referenced. I appreciate the alternate queries you have provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name,
       ccu.table_schema AS foreign_schema,
       ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
       ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND ccu.table_schema = 'b'
AND ccu.table_name='main'
AND ccu.column_name = 'id';
```

Comment: Your answer was more like "select all table names where b.main.id is referenced". Did I miss something? The results I was hoping for would (essentially) be a join on all the tables that reference the primary key.